# Centre an image horizontally, not vertically

Tags: react-native

I would like to have an image that is scaled to fill the parent container's width, while maintaining aspect ratio.

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.bgContainer} resizeMode='contain' source={require('./app/images/green.png')} />
        <Text>text</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flexDirection:'column',
  },
  bgContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  }
});
```

This is my result:

[image]

I do not want image to take up more space that its scaled height, I would like the result to be like this:

[image]

Comment: did you try: `aspectRatio: 1` ?

Comment: aspectRatio not working in react native

Comment: @MeysamIzadmehr are we talking about same thing? http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.44/docs/layout-props.html#aspectratio

Comment: @Cherniv, sorry. I didn't know about `aspectRatio` in `Layout Props`, I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

As @Cherniv comment, use `aspectRatio: 1` is enough. So, there is no need to calculate it manually. Just add it to `bgContainer`.

**old**

You added `flex: 1` to the image. Which is the only child of the parent with `flex: 1`. So, it covers the entire parent. First, remove the flex. Make the aspect ratio of the image, and use screen width to generate the height of the image relativity:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image,Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.bgContainer} resizeMode='contain' source={require('./app/images/green.png')} />
       <Text>text</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flexDirection:'column',
  },
  bgContainer: {
   width: width,
   height: imageHeight * width / imageWidth, // imageHeight & imageWidth are from your image pixel dimensions
   justifyContent: 'flex-start',
 }
});
```